# SingleEmailMessage Bounce Message Not Recieved

Tags: email

When using singleEmailMessage I would expect to get a failure or bounce notification if the email cannot be delivered.  The code below sends successfully to a valid email address but does not fail or generate a bounce message report when an invalid email address is used.  Anyone know why I am not getting a bounce email notification?  Or how I could get this notification.  Thank You!!

```
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

mail.setToAddresses(new String[]{'bpirihINVALID@mydomain.com'} );
mail.setHtmlBody('testhtml');
mail.setPlainTextBody('test plain text');
mail.setSubject('Test Failure');
mail.setBccSender(false);
mail.setUseSignature(false);

mail.setSaveAsActivity(false);

list emailList = new list();
emailList.add(mail);


Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail1 = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

mail1.setToAddresses(new String[]{'bpirih@mydomain.com'} );
mail1.setHtmlBody('testhtml');
mail1.setPlainTextBody('test plain text');
mail1.setSubject('Test Successful');
mail1.setBccSender(false);
mail1.setUseSignature(false);

mail1.setSaveAsActivity(false);

emailList.add(mail1);



list results = Messaging.sendEmail( emailList, false);

            for( Messaging.SendEmailResult currentResult : results ) 
            {
                system.debug(currentResult.isSuccess());

                if ( !currentResult.isSuccess() )
                {
                    Messaging.SendEmailError[] errors = currentResult.getErrors();

                    if( null != errors ) 
                    {
                        for( Messaging.SendEmailError currentError : errors ) 
                        {
                            system.debug('currentError: ' + currentError);
                            system.debug(currentError.getStatusCode() + ' ' + currentError.getMessage());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: I suspect it doesn't work like this because it takes a while for a bounce message to get back and the code is then already finished.

Comment: Not according to the docs:  http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_sendemail.htm

The email address of the logged-in user is inserted in the From Address field of the email header. All return email and out-of-office replies go to logged-in user. If bounce management is enabled, bounces are processed by Salesforce automatically, and the appropriate record is updated; otherwise, they go to the logged-in user.  Bounce management will not intercept these emails as I'm not listing targetobjectId.. Thank you though..

Answer (score 2):

From salesforce support

"SendEmail "success" indicates that the salesforce.com MTA tentatively accepted the email. It is actually placed into a mail queue for later delivery (only after the current transaction completes). This is necessary because salesforce.com does not send the email until after the transaction completes. Any uncaught exception will cancel the email from being sent, as if it hadn't happened. There's no programmatic access to email logs; the "Request Email Log" actually queries the MTA's logs for emails sent from the organization. This data isn't specifically stored "in salesforce.com" proper, and thus, there's no access to the information directly."

Comment: Does the logged in user still receive the bounce back?

Comment: no the logged in user does not get any bounce notifications.

Comment: That's strange, you wouldn't ever get a failure in apex, i.e. a sendEmailError related to a bounce back (email is too slow for that), but you shouldn't be getting the email failure. Seems like support may have been responding to the apex related question, but not your bounce back issue which might merit further inquiry with support.